# In circuitikz for mos symbols can I reduce the source drain extensions?

Tags: circuitikz

[image]    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{circuitikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}

```
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{circuitikz}
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}


\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{circuitikz}[node distance = 8mm and 16mm]
\draw (0,0) node (nmos1) [nmos, xscale=-1, label=left:M1]  {}
            node (nmos2) [nmos,right=of nmos1,label=right:M2] {};
  \end{circuitikz}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you perhaps consider adding a sketch of what you want to achieve? (I guess you're not just looking for a simple `scale=0.7`, are you?)

Comment: The reason I want to remove these source drain wires is because I am using nmos as a capacitor and I do not require these long wires.

Comment: So why don't you just use a capacitor symbol?  Functionally, that is what it is, even if it was intended for something else.

Comment: Implementing as a MOS in to convey the circuit choice made.  The actual capacitor is a combination of metal capacitors and MOS devices and that is the picture I am trying to make.

Answer (score 1):

For formatting purposes, I am entering this as an answer.  The following are the (adjustable) default setting for nmos.

```
\ctikzset{tripoles/nmos/width=.7}
\ctikzset{tripoles/nmos/gate height=.35}
\ctikzset{tripoles/nmos/base height=.5}
\ctikzset{tripoles/nmos/conn height=0}
\ctikzset{tripoles/nmos/height=1.1}
\ctikzset{tripoles/nmos/base width=.5}
\ctikzset{tripoles/nmos/gate width=.62}
\ctikzset{tripoles/nmos/bodydiode scale=.3}
\ctikzset{tripoles/nmos/bodydiode distance=.3}
\ctikzset{tripoles/nmos/bodydiode conn=.6}
\ctikzset{tripoles/nmos/curr direction=1}
```